# Will KDE Backports provide KDE 5.25 for Kubuntu 22.04?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

As in title, I wonder if there will be KDE Plasma 5.25 available for Kubuntu 22.04 in KDE Backports. So far, new versions have been delivered smoothly.

Comment: I Followed this https://www.debugpoint.com/upgrade-kde-plasma-5-25/ but no luck

Comment: I also checked that Fedora 36 also has no updates to 5.25 yet

Comment: Fedora 36 already has update to 5.25.2

Comment: You may want to use KDE Neon, which has the latest version of Plasma with the LTS versions of Ubuntu in the backend (KDE Neon has not released 22.04 yet, but it would be released within a few months). https://neon.kde.org/

Answer (score 2):

No. NOT the *backports* PPA.

---

As said at [kubuntu.org](https://kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-25-beta-available-for-testing/) you could use Kubuntu 22.10 development build (installation 'from scratch'), or in 22.04 use [the **beta** PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/beta), which brings the  Plasma 5.24.90 ( = Plasma 5.25 Beta, which is less recent.)

[image]

**But seriously consider the disclaimer at that page!!**

---

To get even sooner the more bleed-edge 5.25 - as indicated [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum/currently-supported-releases/kubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish/software-support-be/663874-plasma-5-25-on-kubuntu-backports?p=663890#post663890) - one could use the [backports-landing PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports-landing).

I am posting this for reference only, and in a way in order to **advise against it !...**

Anyway, *you* should take all responsibility!

As far as I can tell, I had the following experience: updating from the beta PPA all seemed good. But, as I then found about the "landing" PPA supposed to bring the "real" 5.25, I have updated from that too **without removing first the beta PPA (!)**: after that  ***I couldn't log in after reboot, as no Plasma "session" -- and no other session whatever was available in the login screen!!***

Anyway, if you must, one recommendation would be that, if you update from one PPA and after a while you want to update from a second PPA, before doing *that*: remove the first PPA and downgrade the system to LTS using `ppa-purge`.

Best advice is to wait until you can upgrade to a pre-release of 22.10, thus going out of LTS on a smoother path.

---

So, you will get the floating panel many people seem crazy about already.

[image]

(I personally don't think it's really such a great improvement, I don't see why we have to have an empty space between the panel and the screen margin. Everyone is entitled to one's peculiarities -- I for example "love" full transparent panel, something which makes the floating invisible, except for that empty space --, but promoting this new option as an obvious good thing is ridiculous imo... Testing a "stable" 5.25.2 in Fedora 36 I can say that I see nothing *really* noticeable as a difference from 5.24!... -- Don't even start me about the astounding new settings for taking tint from wallpaper and so forth...! -- Even the promising overview doesn't make much sense as it stands now along activities, the grid and krunner. I cannot see exactly what does it bring more than the grid + krunner and most launchers already do. I guess in the end it will replace them all.)

Comment: This question is incorrect, see my answer below. Plasma 5.25 will be in backports, it is still being tested.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this as well and today I found the official backport from kubuntu to enable 5.25.5 for Kubuntu 24.04.

https://kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-25-for-jammy-22-04-available-via-ppa/

Answer (score 0):

According to [Kubuntu's LTS Policy](https://community.kde.org/Kubuntu/Policies#Long_Term_Support_.28LTS.29) (further confirmed by this [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/vc2pnj/comment/icbnol5/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)), Kubuntu 22.04 will get Plasma 5.25 (and the following updates as long as it's possible) via the [backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports).

However, it is still currently being tested in the [backports-landing PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports-landing). Once it is deemed stable enough, it will be pushed to backports. Until then, you can use backports-landing if you're okay with some bugs and will report them.